# php script in wamp giving error "not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: php, wamp, exec

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>xxxxxx!</h2>

<script language="php">

$score = array();
exec("D:\Users\Owner\Documents\a2 2>&1 D:\Users\Owner\Documents\212.wav D:\Users\Owner\Documents\StartUp\23sw1.wav", $score);
#echo "<h3>Score </h3>\n";
echo "<br />xxxxxxx: $score[0]\n";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Error message:

> 'D:\Users\Owner\Documents\a2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: First: is there an executable file at "D:\Users\Owner\Documents\a2"? Secondly, try double-escaping your backslashes ("D:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\a2"). Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, a2 is an executable - I tried the double-escaping the backslashes. No difference. Identical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run PHP code in that way, PHP exists only on the Server and that is how you flag to the broswer that you want to run a client side language like `javascript`

So you could try

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>xxxxxx!</h2>
<?php
    $score = array();
    exec("D:\Users\Owner\Documents\a2 2>&1 D:\Users\Owner\Documents\212.wav D:\Users\Owner\Documents\StartUp\23sw1.wav", $score);
    echo '<h3>Score </h3>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'xxxxxxx: ' . $score[0];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Your code will now be run when the server is preparing the page prior to sending it to the browser, which I assume is what you wanted to do.

Also you do not need the `\n` everywhere, that just generates unnecessary noice and extra bytes to transfer to the browser, which will ignore them.

Comment: Thanks Riggs. Unfortunately the one you modified is not running. I am using Ubuntu on VM to do this - spent 30 mins trying to get it to run but it does not - no error message - if I remove the php part the html part is running. I got the original code running on Ubuntu on VM. Why?

Comment: This line -> echo 'xxxxxxx: ' . $score[0]; causing the issue - if I change it to echo "xxxxxxx:  $score[0]"; then works - why?

Comment: What issue does it cause?

Comment: The xxxxx has a variable - $Name. Am I correct that this means, it has to be within double quotes? The issue is the php script did not run - when I put double quotes, it ran.

Comment: If you show what the code REALLY is you get a real answer, if you obfiscate, then what am I supposed to do I am not clarevoyant

Comment: Here is the exact line:  echo "<br />$Name's score is: $score[0]\n";

Comment: What is "dot" doing just before $score[0] in echo 'xxxxxxx: ' . $score[0];?

Comment: $score is declared as an array and $score[0] catches a set of numbers - how can I split them - say$score[0] prints 21 20 11 8 79 100  89 and so on - I wan to pick up the last number which is 89?

Comment: I thing you should ask that as a new question.